# Datatables.net Buttons not displaying

Tags: jquery, datatables

I cannot get buttons to display in a datatables.net table. I have tried adding every script related to buttons and every initialization example given on datatables.net, but they do not appear. Here is my current test code:

```js
$(function() {

  $('#myTable').DataTable({
    'buttons': ['copy', 'csv', 'excel']
  });

});
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/dataTables.jqueryui.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/css/buttons.jqueryui.css" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/pdfmake.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/dataTables.jqueryui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/dataTables.buttons.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.jqueryui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.colVis.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.flash.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.html5.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.print.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <table id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td>$320,800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2011/07/25</td>
        <td>$170,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
        <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2009/01/12</td>
        <td>$86,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
        <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2012/03/29</td>
        <td>$433,060</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Airi Satou</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>2008/11/28</td>
        <td>$162,700</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2012/12/02</td>
        <td>$372,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>59</td>
        <td>2012/08/06</td>
        <td>$137,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>55</td>
        <td>2010/10/14</td>
        <td>$327,900</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>39</td>
        <td>2009/09/15</td>
        <td>$205,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Sonya Frost</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>2008/12/13</td>
        <td>$103,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jena Gaines</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2008/12/19</td>
        <td>$90,560</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
        <td>Support Lead</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2013/03/03</td>
        <td>$342,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Charde Marshall</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>36</td>
        <td>2008/10/16</td>
        <td>$470,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
        <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>2012/12/18</td>
        <td>$313,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>2010/03/17</td>
        <td>$385,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Michael Silva</td>
        <td>Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2012/11/27</td>
        <td>$198,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Paul Byrd</td>
        <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>64</td>
        <td>2010/06/09</td>
        <td>$725,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Gloria Little</td>
        <td>Systems Administrator</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>59</td>
        <td>2009/04/10</td>
        <td>$237,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bradley Greer</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>41</td>
        <td>2012/10/13</td>
        <td>$132,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Dai Rios</td>
        <td>Personnel Lead</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>35</td>
        <td>2012/09/26</td>
        <td>$217,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
        <td>Development Lead</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2011/09/03</td>
        <td>$345,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Yuri Berry</td>
        <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>2009/06/25</td>
        <td>$675,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Caesar Vance</td>
        <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>2011/12/12</td>
        <td>$106,450</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Doris Wilder</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>Sidney</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>2010/09/20</td>
        <td>$85,600</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add [dom: 'B'](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) at DataTable initialization.

The snippet:

```js
$('#myTable').DataTable({
    dom: 'B',
    buttons: ['copy', 'csv', 'excel']
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/dataTables.jqueryui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/css/buttons.jqueryui.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/pdfmake.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/dataTables.jqueryui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/dataTables.buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.jqueryui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.colVis.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.flash.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.html5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.print.js"></script>


<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2011/07/25</td>
        <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
        <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2009/01/12</td>
        <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
        <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2012/03/29</td>
        <td>$433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Airi Satou</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>2008/11/28</td>
        <td>$162,700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2012/12/02</td>
        <td>$372,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>59</td>
        <td>2012/08/06</td>
        <td>$137,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>55</td>
        <td>2010/10/14</td>
        <td>$327,900</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>39</td>
        <td>2009/09/15</td>
        <td>$205,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sonya Frost</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>2008/12/13</td>
        <td>$103,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jena Gaines</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2008/12/19</td>
        <td>$90,560</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
        <td>Support Lead</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2013/03/03</td>
        <td>$342,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Charde Marshall</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>36</td>
        <td>2008/10/16</td>
        <td>$470,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
        <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>2012/12/18</td>
        <td>$313,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>2010/03/17</td>
        <td>$385,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Michael Silva</td>
        <td>Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2012/11/27</td>
        <td>$198,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Paul Byrd</td>
        <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>64</td>
        <td>2010/06/09</td>
        <td>$725,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Gloria Little</td>
        <td>Systems Administrator</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>59</td>
        <td>2009/04/10</td>
        <td>$237,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bradley Greer</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>41</td>
        <td>2012/10/13</td>
        <td>$132,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Dai Rios</td>
        <td>Personnel Lead</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>35</td>
        <td>2012/09/26</td>
        <td>$217,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
        <td>Development Lead</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2011/09/03</td>
        <td>$345,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Yuri Berry</td>
        <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>2009/06/25</td>
        <td>$675,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Caesar Vance</td>
        <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>2011/12/12</td>
        <td>$106,450</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Doris Wilder</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>Sidney</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>2010/09/20</td>
        <td>$85,600</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I had used the dom property in testing but didn't have all of my required dependencies included at that time. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on gaetanoM's answer, I tried to identify the minimum required commands and references to make Datatables Buttons work. This is what I came up with:

```
  $(function () {

        $('#myTable').DataTable({
            dom: 'B',
            buttons: true
        });

    });
```

Or variant with specific buttons and the rest of the dom options:

```
$(function () {

    $('#myTable').DataTable({
        dom: 'lBfrtiBp',
        buttons: ['copy', 'excel', 'csv', 'pdf', 'print' ]
    });

});
```

And these appear to be the required includes if using jQuery Datatables:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/dataTables.jqueryui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/css/buttons.jqueryui.css" />
```

Required for Datatables to function:

```
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"
src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.js"
```

Optional for Datatables to function:

```
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"
src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/dataTables.jqueryui.js"
```

Required for any Buttons to appear:

```
src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/dataTables.buttons.js"
src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.html5.js"
```

If Print button or buttons:true, this is required for any Buttons or Dom items to appear:

```
src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.print.js"
```

Required for Excel button to appear:

```
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.js"
```

Required for PDF button to appear:

```
src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/pdfmake.js"
```

Optional, breaks formatting on buttons if jqueryui is used but this is not included:

```
src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.jqueryui.js"
```

Complete example:

```js
    $(function () {

        $('#myTable').DataTable({
                "dom": 'lBfrtiBp',
            'buttons': ['copy', 'excel', 'csv', 'pdf', 'print' ]
        });

    });
```

```html
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/dataTables.jqueryui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/css/buttons.jqueryui.css" />
    
   <!--Required for Datatables to function-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

   <!--Optional for Datatables to function-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/dataTables.jqueryui.js"></script>

   <!--Required for any Buttons to appear-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/dataTables.buttons.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.html5.js"></script>
    
   <!--If Print button or buttons:true, this is required for any Buttons or Dom items to appear -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.print.js"></script>
   
   <!--Required for Excel button to appear-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.js"></script>
   <!--Required for PDF button to appear-->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/pdfmake.js"></script>

    
   <!--Optional, breaks formatting on butons if jqueryui is used but this is not included-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.jqueryui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <table id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr><th>Name</th><th>Position</th><th>Office</th><th>Age</th><th>Start date</th><th>Salary</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>Tiger Nixon</td><td>System Architect</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>61</td><td>2011/04/25</td><td>$320,800</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Garrett Winters</td><td>Accountant</td><td>Tokyo</td><td>63</td><td>2011/07/25</td><td>$170,750</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Ashton Cox</td><td>Junior Technical Author</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>66</td><td>2009/01/12</td><td>$86,000</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Cedric Kelly</td><td>Senior Javascript Developer</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>22</td><td>2012/03/29</td><td>$433,060</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Airi Satou</td><td>Accountant</td><td>Tokyo</td><td>33</td><td>2008/11/28</td><td>$162,700</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Brielle Williamson</td><td>Integration Specialist</td><td>New York</td><td>61</td><td>2012/12/02</td><td>$372,000</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Herrod Chandler</td><td>Sales Assistant</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>59</td><td>2012/08/06</td><td>$137,500</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Rhona Davidson</td><td>Integration Specialist</td><td>Tokyo</td><td>55</td><td>2010/10/14</td><td>$327,900</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Colleen Hurst</td><td>Javascript Developer</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>39</td><td>2009/09/15</td><td>$205,500</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Sonya Frost</td><td>Software Engineer</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>23</td><td>2008/12/13</td><td>$103,600</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Jena Gaines</td><td>Office Manager</td><td>London</td><td>30</td><td>2008/12/19</td><td>$90,560</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Quinn Flynn</td><td>Support Lead</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>22</td><td>2013/03/03</td><td>$342,000</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Charde Marshall</td><td>Regional Director</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>36</td><td>2008/10/16</td><td>$470,600</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Haley Kennedy</td><td>Senior Marketing Designer</td><td>London</td><td>43</td><td>2012/12/18</td><td>$313,500</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td><td>Regional Director</td><td>London</td><td>19</td><td>2010/03/17</td><td>$385,750</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Michael Silva</td><td>Marketing Designer</td><td>London</td><td>66</td><td>2012/11/27</td><td>$198,500</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Paul Byrd</td><td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td><td>New York</td><td>64</td><td>2010/06/09</td><td>$725,000</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Gloria Little</td><td>Systems Administrator</td><td>New York</td><td>59</td><td>2009/04/10</td><td>$237,500</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Bradley Greer</td><td>Software Engineer</td><td>London</td><td>41</td><td>2012/10/13</td><td>$132,000</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Dai Rios</td><td>Personnel Lead</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>35</td><td>2012/09/26</td><td>$217,500</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Jenette Caldwell</td><td>Development Lead</td><td>New York</td><td>30</td><td>2011/09/03</td><td>$345,000</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Yuri Berry</td><td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td><td>New York</td><td>40</td><td>2009/06/25</td><td>$675,000</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Caesar Vance</td><td>Pre-Sales Support</td><td>New York</td><td>21</td><td>2011/12/12</td><td>$106,450</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Doris Wilder</td><td>Sales Assistant</td><td>Sidney</td><td>23</td><td>2010/09/20</td><td>$85,600</td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```